# How do I update remote database structure with local changes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, database-design

We currently update manually each remote database table with changes made on local one. I mean adding tables, tables columns, etc. not the data they contain. The remote database is live in production so it's always newer.

The database type is SQL Server a we normally use SSMS to change it on both remote and local machine. The website is ASP.NET MVC4 with EntityFramework 4.2

Thanks.

Comment: You could write update scripts and run them against each database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSMS in your local database, after you make changes to the table in design view, if you right click on an empty white row at the bottom you can select 'Generate change script'. This will generate a script which you can then run on the remote server to automatically apply your changes that were made to the local database.

Comment: Nice, what about updating relationships?

Comment: It will generate any changes you made. This includes primary and foreign key changes as well as relationships. It will generate scripts for ALL changes made.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the tables automatically (not sure if thats what you ask), you should check out Migrations for EF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx